# Remove base64 value from string column in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, base64

I have a text column in a table that contains HTML data along with image represented in base64 encoding.

Here is an example:

```
</p><p><span lang="EN">&nbsp;</span></p><p>
</p><p><img width="263" height="135" align="right" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA...." alt=""></p>
```

The string after `base64` is really long. I want to remove the long string representation and replace with the word "image".

I tried a pattern match on `base64,` and remove everything after that until `"` mark before the `alt` keyword. It worked on cases where there is only occurrence of a base64 value. When there are multiple occurrences, it fails.

Is there a better way to approach this problem in order to remove just the string representing image in base64 encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the actual replacement work more than just once, you need to use the "global" flag for the `regexp_replace`, e.g.:

```sql
=# SELECT regexp_replace(E'\n\n...height="135" align="right" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA...." alt="" ...\n<p></p>\n<p><img align="left" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA...." class="test" alt=""/>\n', '(data:[^,]+,)[^"]+', '\1<data>', 'g');
                                regexp_replace                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                             +
                                                                             +
 ...height="135" align="right" src="data:image/png;base64,<data>" alt="" ...  +
 <p></p>                                                                     +
 <p><img align="left" src="data:image/png;base64,<data>" class="test" alt=""/>+

(1 row)
```

...so: `regexp_replace(my_html_column, '(data:[^,]+,)[^"]+', '\1<data>', 'g')`

That should match and replace all [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Syntax)'s of the given text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem id the greedy match, and the solution is to match anything but `"` characters:

```
regexp_replace(col, 'base64,[^"]*', 'image')
```